# How to catch rake task exit status in another rake task

Tags: ruby, rake, exit-code, rake-task, exitstatus

#### Problem

I have something like this:

```
task :fail do
  exit 111
end

task :run_fail_and_succeed do
  begin
    Rake::Task['knapsack:fail'].invoke
  rescue
    exit 0
  end
end
```

I would like to run task `:fail` and handle it's exit status. Than exit with `0`. How can I do that?

#### Notes:

1. It can't be asynchronous / parallel / run in a background. `:fail` must finish before `:run_fail_and_succeed`.
2. It would be nice not only to exit with 0, but really handle this status code, so I could do different things based on it's value

Answer (score 6):

`rescue` with a specific type of exception type. In your case, this should be `SystemExit`. Then you can check the fields associated with that exception.

```
task :run_fail_and_succeed do
  begin
    Rake::Task['knapsack:fail'].invoke
  rescue SystemExit => e
    puts e.status #=> 111
    # now you can handle your logic according to the exit status
  end
end
```

Comment: What if a task I run inside doesn't return exception? It execute some command inside, this command fail with error code, but my rescue block isn't called after all.